# PDE Using Fourier Series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to find the solution to(I don't need to find the coefficient):

$v_t = kv_{x x} , 0 < x < l, 0 < t < ∞$

$v(0, t) = 0$

$v_x(l, t) = 0$

$v(x, 0) = −U$

Where U is a constant

This the answer that I get:

$$v(x, t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n e^{-(\frac{n\pi}{l})^2kt}
sin(\frac{nπx}{l})$$
which comes directly from separating the variables of $v(x,t)$ 
But the correct answer is this:

$$v(x, t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n e^{-(\frac{(n+1/2)\pi}{l})^2kt}
sin(\frac{(n + 1/2)πx}{l})$$

why do I have to add the $\frac{1}{2}$ to $n$?

Comment: Perhaps show how you arrived at your answer so we can help you identify where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't satisfy the second boundary condition. Your solution satisfies the boundary conditions $$v(0,t) = 0 \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, v(l,t) = 0, $$ whereas you need it to satisfy $$v(0,t) = 0 \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, \frac{dv}{dx}(l,t) = 0.$$ Adding the $1/2$ accomplishes that.

Comment: Would you know how to solve problem with the new boundary condition? Unfortunately I was just given the formula without any real explanation of how it was derived.

Comment: Assume a separable solution $v(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$ and find simple ODEs that $X(x)$ and $T(t)$ solve (there will be infinitely many such ODEs, one for each natural number maybe so superposing the solutions at the end gives the infinite sum). How did you get your solution?